# Fastest way to get big data from warehouse to server

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, cloud, pagespeed

What is the fastest way to query data from a simple structured table? Talking about milliseconds here.. And what is the best cloud to use?

The table has around 500k rows but could get larger and has a size of around 20 gb.

It doesn't matter what cloud Plattform to use. It doesn't matter how much it costs. Should I split up the data into multiple tables and use some kind of threading?

Semi-structured, unstructured? -> structured

Access mode ? -> simple key/value access

Is your service local to a region or must be global? -> can be both

Is the data change often, or they are mostly static? -> mostly static

Comment: Your question lacks the details that would be required. You are also asking for an opinion on the fastest method to do something with unknown services. there are many ways to query data. The data is a factor in selecting the appropriate query. Rewrite your post into a question that can be answered with facts and/or citations.

Comment: Agree with John. Can you provide details on the data? Structured. Semi-structured, unstructured? Access mode (complexe queries, join, or simple key/value access)? Is your service local to a region or must be global? Is the data change often, or they are mostly static?

Comment: @JohnHanley I updated the question accordingly. Now any chance you can help me?

Comment: The details I need are not in your post

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere can you answer with the details given?

Comment: Memory store will have the lowest latency. Here an article for multiregion: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/creating-regional-replicas-for-cloud-memorystore-for-redis

Comment: Hi @RobinBjoernPlatte, Is your issue resolved? If not, could you elaborate more on your use case? From where you are trying to extract data? Does [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery) help you? Please follow these [StackOverflow guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to ask the question.